# How to map Option+X but not change Option+Shift+X in KeyRemap4Macbook?

Tags: keyboard

I want to map Option+X to something. But this mapping effects Option+Shift+X key binding as a side effect. Is there a way to prevent it?

Here is an example mapping that I use:

```
<item>
    <name>movement home</name>
    <identifier>private.movehome</identifier>
    <not>VIRTUALMACHINE</not>
    <autogen>
        --KeyToKey--
        KeyCode::C,ModifierFlag::OPTION_L,
        KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT,ModifierFlag::FN
    </autogen>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<autogen>
  __KeyToKey__
  KeyCode::C, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE,
  KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::FN
</autogen>
```

The use of `| ModifierFlag::NONE` prevents other key combinations from being remapped.

Answer (score -1):

Try **System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys ->** Change whatever..

or

Try **System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts**?

Hope I helped??

Comment: Can you expand on your solution? What do you mean by '*Change whatever*'? How does changing shortcuts disable remapping of a third key in KeyRemap4MacBook as was the original intent of the question?

Comment: well he didnt explain really just tagged "keyboard" and asked to change shortcut.. thats how i understood it.. no need to downvote.. vote every other answer down to make yours rise.. thats pathetic kiddo! :)